# Не добавляется новый источник данных с помощью UI конструктора

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

Использую Windows Forms .NET 6.0. 
К элементу DataGridView пытаюсь добавить источник данных.
[image: Добавление нового источника данных]

Выбираю класс, свойства которого я хочу видеть в элементе.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRI7R.png
Нажимаю ОК и больше ничего не происходит.

Пробовал другие пункты в списке выбирать - ничего.
Пробовал через свойства добавлять, тоже ничего.

Смотрел документацию, там сказано что, проекты winform и wpf, на .NET не поддерживают окно "источники данных", и нужно выбирать .NET Framework. Я подумал что это основная причина, но вчера у меня спокойно подключало источники данных и я видел свойства класса в элементе DataGridView.

Я делаю что-то не правильно? Получается нужно вручную прописывать BindingSource к DataGridView?

UPD: Создал новый проект winform, там всё работает нормально, всё подключается. csproj проектов идентичен. Но когда пытаюсь добавить новый источник данных, то добавляется строка `<ItemGroup> <Folder Include="Properties\" /> </ItemGroup>` , хотя в проекте, где всё работает она не добавляется.

Answer (score 0):

Попытался в ручную добавить новую папку в Properties с названием DataSources и мне написало что такая папка уже существует. Перешёл в локальную директорию проекта и удалил папку. Всё заработало.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня была такая же проблема.

Comment: @Phedrone , пожалуйста

Comment: "тихо сам с собою...я веду беседу"